# How to avoid JasperReport's report row split in Excel?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am generating Excel report using **jasperreports-6.1.0.jar**. I am getting row split issue in excel when text field length is more than 220 characters.

[image]

JRXML details:

```
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement uuid="55da47e9-de3c-45ac-9b42-c0b9ee2bdcce" style="Sans_Normal" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="775" y="0" width="27" height="70" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
            </box>
            <textElement>
                <font size="10"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{annotationValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

I added below jrxml property for entire report:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Unfortunately, all attempts to use the properties to solve the problem have been unsuccessful.

I solved the problem by setting the **Split Type** property of the **Detail** section to **Prevent**.